# Reason for crashing of created window in C

Tags: c++, c, windows, getch, createwindow

When I create a window in C using the  `CreateWindow()` function, it works fine it just disappears instantly, so I used the `getch()` function to try to resolve the issue but it does not work. The window does not display the button, and crashes.

But when I used `MessageBox()` instead of `getch()`, it stays and functions normally. I am trying to figure out why this happens.

I tried many things, like using `MessageBox()` and `getch()` together, using `getch()` before and after `ShowWindow()`, but every time it gives me some interesting result but not the normal functionality of the window.

Code that works:

```
#include <windows.h>

int _stdcall WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND h;
    HINSTANCE i;
    h = CreateWindow("Button", "XYZ", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 15, 20, 250, 200, 0, 0, i, 0);
    ShowWindow(h, nCmdShow);
    MessageBox(0, "Stop", "Wait", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Code that does not work:

```
#include <windows.h>

int _stdcall WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND h;
    HINSTANCE i;
    h = CreateWindow("Button", "XYZ", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 15, 20, 250, 200, 0, 0, i, 0);
    ShowWindow(h, nCmdShow);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know the reason for this error. I think it is because `getch()` is a DOS function, but still the compiler should at least show a warning.

Comment: How did you establish that the program crashed exactly? Are you sure it didn't terminate normally?

Comment: You need to find a resource to teach you Win32 API programming properly. You aren't going to get very far by trying random things.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The program stops responding and a pop up appears to end task.

Comment: @john How should I start that because this was just a brief topic at the end of a C programming book, just to get people interested in windows programming i guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no crash in this code.

Your `getch()` example simply lacks a message loop needed to service the window, and also `getch()` is meaningless in a non-console app. So your `WinMain()` exits immediately after showing the button window.

Whereas your `MessageBox()` example has a message loop (inside of `MessageBox()` itself) which keeps `WinMain()` running, and the button window processong UI messages, until the `MessageBox` dialog is closed.

Also, it doesn't make sense to try to display a button as its own overlapped window. You should be registering and creating a separate overlapped window that then creates the button as a child.  User actions on the button are sent to the button's parent window, so you need to create a parent window for it.

Comment: Sorry, but I am very new to Windows Programming (this is just the 2nd program i wrote) and the author of the book ,that i referred for this program, describes the use of MessageBox() as getch() is used in a classic C program, to make the output to stay on the screen.So, if you could simplify your answer or suggest a better way I could learn Win32 programming

Comment: @PoseidonBroger get yourself a better book to learn from, and also read [MSDN's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/windowing).